# SQL-Query: help needed

Tags: mysql

i need help to build a result-query:

**Tbl. Main:**

```
id  | Title
205 | Main_A
206 | Main_B
207 | Main_C
208 | Main_D
209 | Main_E
210 | Main_F
211 | Main_G
212 | Main_H
```

**Tbl. Sub:**

```
id  | parent__main_id | Title
401 | 205              | Sub_A
402 | 205              | Sub_B
403 | 207              | Sub_C
404 | 209              | Sub_D
405 | 209              | Sub_E
406 | 210              | Sub_F
407 | 211              | Sub_G
408 | 212              | Sub_H
```

Tbl. Cat and Pro are supported by Tbl. Sub:

**Tbl. Cat:**

```
id  | parent__sub_id | Title
808 | 401            | Cat_A
809 | 401            | Cat_B
810 | 401            | Cat_C
811 | 401            | Cat_D
812 | 403            | Cat_E
813 | 404            | Cat_F
```

**Tbl. Pro:**

```
id  | parent__sub_id | Title
920 | 402            | Pro_A
921 | 402            | Pro_B
922 | 405            | Pro_C
923 | 406            | Pro_D
924 | 406            | Pro_E
925 | 406            | Pro_F
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
205 | Main_A | 401 | Sub_A | 808 | Cat_A
205 | Main_A | 401 | Sub_A | 809 | Cat_B
205 | Main_A | 401 | Sub_A | 810 | Cat_C
205 | Main_A | 401 | Sub_A | 811 | Cat_D
205 | Main_A | 402 | Sub_B | 920 | Pro_A
205 | Main_A | 402 | Sub_B | 921 | Pro_B
206 | Main_B | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
207 | Main_C | 403 | Sub_C | 812 | Cat_E
208 | Main_D | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
209 | Main_E | 404 | Sub_D | 813 | Cat_F
209 | Main_E | 405 | Sub_E | 922 | Pro_C
209 | Main_F | 406 | Sub_F | 923 | Pro_D
209 | Main_F | 406 | Sub_F | 924 | Pro_E
210 | Main_F | 406 | Sub_F | 925 | Pro_F
211 | Main_G | 407 | Sub_G | NULL | NULL
212 | Main_H | 408 | Sub_H | NULL | NULL
```

Can someone help me? Thanks...

gondor

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Search `LEFT JOINS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here is a complete solution, along with the code to create the test.

### let's first create the data

```
CREATE TABLE `Tbl_Main` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ;

insert into Tbl_Main (id,Title) values ( 205 , "Main_A" ), ( 206 , "Main_B" ), ( 207 , "Main_C" ), ( 208 ,     "Main_D" ), ( 209 , "Main_E" ), ( 210 , "Main_F" ), ( 211 , "Main_G" ), ( 212 , "Main_H" );

CREATE TABLE `Tbl_Sub` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent__main_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);

insert into Tbl_Sub (id,parent__main_id,Title) values ( 401 , 205 , 'Sub_A' ), ( 402 , 205 , 'Sub_B' ), (     403 , 207 , 'Sub_C' ), ( 404 , 209 , 'Sub_D' ), ( 405 , 209 , 'Sub_E' ), ( 406 , 210 , 'Sub_F' ), ( 407 ,     211 , 'Sub_G' ), ( 408 , 212 , 'Sub_H' );

CREATE TABLE `Tbl_Cat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent__sub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);

insert into Tbl_Cat (id,parent__sub_id,Title) values ( 808 , 401 , "Cat_A" ), ( 809 , 401 , "Cat_B" ), (     810 , 401 , "Cat_C" ), ( 811 , 401 , "Cat_D" ), ( 812 , 403 , "Cat_E" ), ( 813 , 404 , "Cat_F" );

CREATE TABLE `Tbl_Pro` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent__sub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
);

insert into Tbl_Pro (id,parent__sub_id,Title) values ( 920 , 402 , "Pro_A" ), ( 921 , 402 , "Pro_B" ), (     922 , 405 , "Pro_C" ), ( 923 , 406 , "Pro_D" ), ( 924 , 406 , "Pro_E" ), ( 925 , 406 , "Pro_F" );
```

### Here is the solution

```
select Tbl_Main.* , sub1.sub_id, sub1.sub_title, sub1.last_id, sub1.last_title from Tbl_Main
left join 
(
  (
  select s.id 'sub_id' , s.Title 'sub_title' , s.parent__main_id , l.id 'last_id' , l.Title 'last_title' 
  from Tbl_Sub s
  join Tbl_Cat l
  on s.id = l.parent__sub_id
) UNION (
  select s.id 'sub_id' , s.Title 'sub_title' , s.parent__main_id , l.id 'last_id' , l.Title 'last_title' 
  from Tbl_Sub s
  join Tbl_Pro l
  on s.id = l.parent__sub_id
  )
) sub1
on Tbl_Main.id = sub1.parent__main_id
order by Tbl_Main.id , sub1.sub_id , sub1.last_id;
```

### and finally, the output

```
'205','Main_A','401','Sub_A','808','Cat_A'
'205','Main_A','401','Sub_A','809','Cat_B'
'205','Main_A','401','Sub_A','810','Cat_C'
'205','Main_A','401','Sub_A','811','Cat_D'
'205','Main_A','402','Sub_B','920','Pro_A'
'205','Main_A','402','Sub_B','921','Pro_B'
'206','Main_B',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'207','Main_C','403','Sub_C','812','Cat_E'
'208','Main_D',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'209','Main_E','404','Sub_D','813','Cat_F'
'209','Main_E','405','Sub_E','922','Pro_C'
'210','Main_F','406','Sub_F','923','Pro_D'
'210','Main_F','406','Sub_F','924','Pro_E'
'210','Main_F','406','Sub_F','925','Pro_F'
'211','Main_G',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
'212','Main_H',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

## So how does it work / How did I solve it ?

I noticed two things immediately

1. The first two columns *look suspiciously* like the very first table.  That is a major hint to me that the first column is probably going to be in a join.  That may sound really obvious, but ... well ... sometimes we've got to state the obvious.
2. The last column was a mix of **Cat** and **Pro**.  That is a big clue that I'll need a union of those two tables, or queries that involve those two tables.

So the solution was going to be something like

```
Tbl_Main join ( Tbl_Cat Union  Tbl_Pro )
```

But there is something missing that was needed to connect the references from Tbl_Main to Tbl_Cat or Tbl_Pro, and that is Tbl_Sub.

and that's what the solution is:

```
Tbl_Main join ( ( Tbl_Sub join Tbl_Cat ) Union ( Tbl_Sub join Tbl_Pro ) )
```

Cheers!

Comment: @gondor - thanks for the compliment.  Give me an upvote if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT m.id AS mid, 
  m.Title AS mtitle, 
  s.id AS sid, 
  s.Title AS stitle, 
  c.id AS cid, 
  c.Title AS ctitle
FROM Main m
JOIN Sub s
  ON m.id == s.parent__main_id
JOIN Cat c 
  ON s.id == c.parent__sub_id
JOIN Pro p
  ON s.id == p.parent__sub_id;
```

Comment: You should use alias for `Title` as multiple `Title` will overwrite

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need both `Cat` and `Pro` tables' title columns appended in the same result column, in which case you can use two queries with `LEFT JOIN` and `UNION` them, e.g.:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, s.id, s.title, c.id, c.title
FROM Main m LEFT JOIN Sub s ON m.id = s.parent_main_id
LEFT JOIN Cat c ON s.id = c.parent_sub_id

UNION

SELECT m.id, m.title, s.id, s.title, p.id, p.title
FROM Main m LEFT JOIN Sub s ON m.id = s.parent_main_id
LEFT JOIN Pro p ON s.id = p.parent_sub_id
```

This will give you the required result, but not in order of main ids. If you want the result ordered then you can wrap this query into another query and apply order by, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
 SELECT m.id, m.title, s.id, s.title, c.id, c.title
 FROM Main m LEFT JOIN Sub s ON m.id = s.parent_main_id
 LEFT JOIN Cat c ON s.id = c.parent_sub_id

 UNION

 SELECT m.id, m.title, s.id, s.title, p.id, p.title
 FROM Main m LEFT JOIN Sub s ON m.id = s.parent_main_id
 LEFT JOIN Pro p ON s.id = p.parent_sub_id
) a
ORDER BY a.id;
```